# How to add launch parameter to Google Chrome on Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, applescript

I wanna run Chrome on Mac with the parameter `--enable-speech-input`.

Can anyone tell me the steps to do this and the steps to undo this? (If one day I wanna run Chrome without the launch parameter)

Comment: It would be amazing if the mods would point users to the correct stackexchange site when they close questions. I think superuser.com makes sense in this case.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Run Terminal.app then use the following command:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --enable-speech-input
```

This will launch it once using your parameter.  From there you could make an alias to make it easier to launch from the terminal or write an AppleScript to make it double clickable.

Find more information [here](http://www.stevenjaycohen.com/2010/03/05/chromeflix-or-netflix-watch-instantly-for-google-chrome-on-the-mac/).

Comment: @chrisparker2000 your link is dead

Comment: Actually you can use `open` like this: `open -a "Google Chrome" --args`

Comment: Any way to do this on iOS? I want to launch the Chrome app with a specific set of arguments on my iPad...

Comment: After reading [this](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/command-line-flags) I assume that it's impossible @GrayedFox

Comment: @chrisparker, Stuff after `--args` (eg `--user-data-dir=...`) isn't working for me. Do you know why?

Comment: @GrayedFox, did you consider creating an application that will open the Google Chrome on iOS? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61617643/swift-on-macos-open-chrome-with-a-url-as-parameter