# Swift on macOS: open Chrome with a URL as parameter

Tags: swift, macos

I'd like to open Chrome with a specific URL from my macOS app.

I'm trying it like this, but unfortunately it doesn't work.
Chrome is opened, but not with the given URL String.

```
let configuration = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
configuration.arguments = [url.absoluteString]
let appUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Applications/Google Chrome.app")
NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication(at: appUrl,
    configuration: configuration,
    completionHandler: nil)
```

`open()` does not help me in this case, as I don't want to open the standard browser.

Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it.

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open([url],
    withApplicationAt: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"),
    configuration: configuration)
```

did the trick

Comment: You should use `urlForApplication(withBundleIdentifier:)` to obtain the URL rather than hard-coding it. A bundle ID is a much safer way to identify an app than its name or path, which can be changed by the user.

Comment: @KenThomases Thanks for your suggestion. I fully agree.

Comment: Silently fails for me on M1/Ventura/Xcode 14.3