# How to access path sent by `open` command to Swift GUI app

Tags: swift, macos

The `open` command can be used to send files to programs as in this example:

```
open -a "Google Chrome" Untitled.png
```

What would a Swift GUI app use to receive the path sent through that command?

I've tried this in the `init()` function of my main view

```swift
if CommandLine.arguments.count != 1 {
    path = CommandLine.arguments[1]
}
```

but the path doesn't seem to be sent there.

#### Response to Duplicate Question Claim

In [Swift on macOS: open Chrome with a URL as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61617643/swift-on-macos-open-chrome-with-a-url-as-parameter) the question is asking how to open *Chrome* and pass it a URL *from* their app. I am trying to open *my app* and pass it files *from* the `open` command called from the terminal.

Comment: Have you tried this application delegate method? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/2887193-application

Comment: AppKit or SwiftUI?

Comment: @Willeke Either. I don't care as long as it works on macOS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift on macOS: open Chrome with a URL as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61617643/swift-on-macos-open-chrome-with-a-url-as-parameter)

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I don't think so. That looks like someone is trying to open *Chrome* with a URL from their app. I want to open *my app* using the `open` command.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need to use terminal to open the file?

Comment: I want to pass files to the app using a script then have the app execute GUI operations against those files.

Comment: The reason you can't find the arguments is because you didn't pass any arguments in the command. To actually pass in any arguments, you need to specifically use `--args`.

Comment: Great! That works. Feel free to post that as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't find the arguments is because you didn't pass any arguments to the app in your command.

Unlike `MyApp myFileURL`, `open -a MyApp myFileURL` doesn't actually pass `myFileURL` to `MyApp`.

To actually pass any arguments to `MyApp`, you need to specifically use `--args`.